# How to determine if sym link exists

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to determine if a symbolic link exists.  I thought that `-L` or `-f` would do it, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
VHOST="/etc/apache2/sites-available/vhost.local";
if [ ! -L VHOST ]; then
        ln -s /home/user/Ubuntu\ One/htdocs/vhosts/vhost.local VHOST;
        a2ensite vhost.local;
        echo "  -vhost.local":
fi
```

It should create the sym link if there isn't already one....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about too localized

Comment: This question should be closed because it is about a trivial syntax error and will not help future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the `TEST(1)` manpage:

```
   -h FILE
          FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -L)
   -L FILE
          FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -h)
```

`-h` or `-L` should do the trick. However, you are not testing against the **variable** `$VHOST` but the literal `VHOST`. That's the error.

So, I suppose you meant to say:

```
if [ ! -L "$VHOST" ]; then
  ...
```

Additionally you're forgetting a $ in `ln -s`:

```
ln -s /home/user/Ubuntu\ One/htdocs/vhosts/vhost.local "$VHOST";
```